# looking for up to date Maven dependencies/repos

Tags: maven-2, frameworks, jakarta-ee, dependencies, pom.xml

this far i've been working on projects without using any build manager, i've used Maven just once before and found it pretty useful, so i'd like to start implementing it on my new projects.

I'm starting a Web application that uses Hibernate, JPA, Struts2, log4j, Ajax, Apache Commons Jquery and Junit but i'm failing epicly at finding the right dependency declarations to include in my Maven pom.

Is there some up to date list of the repos, artifact id's, etc that i could use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I use: http://mvnrepository.com/

Apart from this I use

- JBoss Maven Repository: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#welcome
- Java Maven2 repo: http://download.java.net/maven/2/ or http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-coping-with-sun-jars.html

I have these repositories in my pom.xml

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
 <repository>
    <id>jboss</id>
    <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

---

Just realized that there is an plug-in for Firefox to look into mvnrepository.com see here:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mvnrepository-search/

Thank you @Sébastien Le Callonnec

*NOTE:* This tool seems to be bit old, on FireFox 3.6, it says, "This search engine isn't supported by Firefox and can't be installed." Sorry for misinformation.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try those, seems to be what i was looking for. :)

Comment: It’s worth mentioning there is a firefox search add-on for mvnrepository there: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mvnrepository-search/

Comment: @Sébastien Le Callonnec thanks, I guess this info should be kept on mvnrepository.com I've been using this repository almost always for years. Never realized there is a FF plugin. Cool.

Comment: @Nishant: This plugin is a life saver, glad you find it useful! ;)

Comment: @Nishant: Odd, it works fine for me on FF 3.6.13...

Comment: @Sébastien Le Callonnec  me too on FF3.6.13 on Windows7 64bit

Answer (score 1):

1. Everything you want is on the default central repo.
2. http://mavencentral.sonatype.com/

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for something like that but was unable to find it googling as i didn't know hot to search for it. +1!